# Konsole in Kubuntu 16.04 does not restore tabs

Tags: kubuntu, konsole

Konsole in previous versions of Kubuntu used to restore all tabs and their CWDs. Apparently it does not any more and I can't seem to find an option to tell it to do so. Konsole version 15.12.3

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I started Kubuntu 16.10 in a virtual machine, opened Konsole, opened some tabs (each using its particular directory), restarted the virtual machine, and Konsole restored the tabs, each using its particular directory.

There was a bug that was solved, but beginning with Kubuntu 16.10. For more information:

- "Plasma doesn't restore everything after a reboot": 
  https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343518
- "Missing some clients or windows when storeSession and performLegacySessionSave": 
  https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354724